# How to set eventOverlap z-index based on event properties

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm developing calendar application based on fullcalendar plugin, where I need to display calendars of other people aswell. Lets say we have two events, one is mine, the second isn't.

```
e1 = {
  start: '2015-08-19 13:37',
  owner: true
}

e2 = {
  start: '2015-08-19 13:37',
  owner: false
}
```

Since both events have same event.start, the overlapping comes to play.
Is it possible to make events where `owner == true` appear obove the others?

Comment: a jsfiddle link would be helpful.

Comment: The only solution without the need to touch fullcalendar source code is to set classname and override its css. http://jsbin.com/joharikata/edit?css,js,output